# Pass Expression<Func<Type, bool>> as TestCase

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, nunit

Does anyone know how I can parameterize following:

```
[Test]
void SelectTest(Expression<Func<MyType, bool>> where)
{
    try
    {
        using (var db = new DataConnection("MyData"))
        {
            where = e => e.Status == Status.New;

            var data = db.GetTable<MyType>()
            .(where.Compile())
            .Select(e => e);

            Assert.IsNotEmpty(data);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Assert.False(true);
    }
}
```

I tried adding a testcase like this:

```
[TestCase(e => e.Status == Status.New)]
```

But I'm getting the following error:

*Expression cannot contain anonymous methods or lambda expressions.*

What am I missing?

(I'm using linq2db and nunit)

Answer (score 3):

Appearantly I can use NUnits TestCaseSource to pass Funcs.

See [Pass lambda to parameterized NUnit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823026/pass-lambda-to-parameterized-nunit-test/10823900)

My Solution:

```
public class SelectCollection
{
    public static IEnumerable<Expression<Func<Evaluation, bool>>> Evaluation
    {
        get
        {
            yield return (e) => e.Status == Status.New;
            yield return (e) => e.Id == 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Used as:

```
[Test]
[TestCaseSource(typeof(SelectCollection), "Evaluation")]
public void SelectTest(Expression<Func<Evaluation, bool>> where)
```

Comment: Yeah you can use test source, however can you see immediately how unreadable the test becomes? What's the chance it will be maintained by other devs?

Comment: I agree but I'm the only one maintaining the tests.. In fact I'm the only one doing unit/integration tests.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass complex expressions as test arguments, only constant primitive types are supported.

Comment: That's what I thought... I guess I'll de-generalize and write query specific tests then..

Comment: Do you have a source to support that?

Comment: @grmbl https://stackoverflow.com/a/1235690/446515  It's a rule in the C# language that's true for all attributes, not only `TestCase`.